# CookieManager not work on background service when closed from recent list

Tags: android, cookies, service, background

This method not working on Android when the app is closed from recent list, and all others code is working fine.

```
CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(COOKIES)
```

I am using Services to execute background processes.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        }
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
```

and will be alright.